# Convert array into array of React components separated by string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I convert an array of string shown below

```
var players = ['ronaldo','messi','naymar','suarez','ozil']
```

into a jsx statement as shown below

```
<b>ronaldo</b> and <b>messi</b> and <b>naymar</b> and <b>suarez</b> and <b>ozil</b> and <b></b>
```

I tried to use `.map` and `.join` as shown below

```
players.map(player => <b>player</b>).join('and');
```

But it rendered out like this

```
[object Object] and [object Object] and [object Object] and [object Object]......
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`join` joins all elements of an array into a string, so it will be hard to use that with JSX, since JSX is just a bunch of `React.createElement` calls under the hood.

You could use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) instead and add `and` for all entries in the array except the last.

```
players.map((p, index) => (
  <Fragment>
    <b> {p} </b> {players.length - 1 !== index && "and"}
  </Fragment>
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Rendering the `<b>` elements using `Array.map()`, and add the "and" between them using a CSS `::before` pseudo element.

```js
const players = ['ronaldo','messi','naymar','suarez','ozil'];

const Demo = ({ players }) => (
  <p>
  {
    players.map(player => (
      <b>{ player }</b>
    ))
  }
  </p>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo players={players} />,
  demo
);
```

```css
b:not(:last-child)::after {
  font-weight: normal;
  content: ' and ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

```
players.map((player,index)=>(
    <div>
       <b>{data}</b>
       {(players.length-1) === i ? '' : ' and '}
    </div>))
```

Comment: I dont want the enclosing <div>

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to achieve this, one using plain HTML composition, the other using an array of arrays:

```js
var players = ['ronaldo','messi','naymar','suarez','ozil'];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: players.map(player => `<b>${player}</b>`).join(' and ') }} /><br/>
        { players.map((player, i) => [<b>{player}</b>, i < players.length - 1 && " and "]) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use map(). Simply use map() function and return anything you want.

Here is JSfiddle link. You can edit it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mustkeom/pqLhw3dg/).

https://jsfiddle.net/mustkeom/pqLhw3dg/

```
<div id="app">test</app>

var players = ['ronaldo','messi','naymar','suarez','ozil']

    let allPlayers = players.map((item, index)=>{

    return <React.Fragment> <b> {item} </b> { index < players.length-1 && 'and'  } </React.Fragment>

    })



ReactDOM.render(
  allPlayers,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Just simple like this. Fragment is just a wrapper and will not render itself.

Comment: There's a fifth "and" at the end of your result.

Comment: Just presented the idea. We can manage this thing with conditions. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try with it

```
var mapped = players.map((item)=>('<b>'+item+'</b>')).join("and");
```

will get you result -

```
<b>ronaldo</b> and<b>messi</b> and<b>naymar</b> and<b>suarez</b> and<b>ozil</b>
```